# Dynamic Javascript function in Django "for" loop

Tags: javascript, django, django-views

In the following Javascript, I would like to replace all text beginning with "#" to become a link and change the color. The function works fine, but it changes all of the descriptions on the page instead of each photo individually. Is there a way to have it work for each photo in the `for loop`?

***Javascript:***

```
var str = $('.description').html();
var edt = str.replace(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig, "$1<a href='{% url "timeline" %}'><span style='color: blue;'>$2</span></a>");
$('.description').html(edt);
```

***Django:***

```
{% for photo in photos %}
    <div class="photo-item">
        <p class="description">{{ photo.description }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Javascript, `$('.description')` returns a list of all the elements that have a class `description`, while the `html()` function

- returns the content of the FIRST element when reading
- modifies EACH element when updating

What you need is something like this (Not tested):

```
$('.description').each(function(index) {
  var str = $(this).html();
  var edt = ...;
  $(this).html(edt);
});
```